# Detect screenshots on Android apps running on Chromebook

Tags: android, react-native, google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I have a react native android application running on Chrome OS. Usually the android app calls a function to disable screenshots on phones like this:

```
    NativeModules.FlagSecure.activate();
```

However, this approach doesn't do anything on Chrome OS; I am able to use the screenshot functionality with `Ctrl + Show Windows` and with the shift-modifier. How would I go about detecting screenshot activity or screen recording on Chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add this flag to a java module.

```
  public static final int FLAG_SECURE
```